# How to add ammo for grenade launcher?

Tags: frozen-synapse-2

Just bought my first grenade unit and assigned him to a team.  I jumped into a Sonata incursion event and by the first turn my unit appears to be just stuck standing around with no ammunition.  Haven't even fired a single shot so far.

[image: Ammunition Remaining: 0]

Was I supposed to load him up before the round somehow?  How do I add ammunition?